# javascript : Not able to open URL with chinese characters in IE 9

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application which uses java script to load files and display content in the browser. But when the file has some chinese characters , the file is not loaded in IE 9.

i am using `encodeURI(url)` to encode the url and using jquery '`load`' function to get the contents of the file. In chrome,safari and fire fox, the file is loaded correctly but in IE 9 ,the page is not loaded ,the response text of the AJAX call is returned as null.  I am wondering if anyone has a solution for this as i find it weird that IE 9 behaves any differently from the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

That seems definitely an encoding problem.

While other browsers set default encoding as UTF-8,

IE does not do that.

Try

```
 encodeURIComponent( url )
```

and

Try without

```
 encodeURIComponent
```

See if it at least works in IE9.